# VS Code: How to reference and alter variables from separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have two separate javascript files due to me needing to run one as `type="module"` in my html (since I'm importing a math library from https://mathjs.org/index.html), and needing to run one as `type="text/javascript"` (as the function inside it wouldn't run inside a module for some reason).

Here is the first js file, app.js:

```
var turn = "X"

function play(cell) {
    cell.value = turn;
    grid[1][2] = X;
    console.log(grid[1][2])
    if(turn == "X")
    {
        turn = "O"
    }
    else 
    {
        turn = "X"
    }
    cell.disabled = true;
}
```

Here is the other js file, mathimport.js:

```
import 'math.js'
import 'mathjs'

var grid = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
export {grid}
```

Here is the important part of my html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="mathimport.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access `grid` from mathimport.js inside app.js, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: grid is not defined
    at play (c:\Users\C2Ran\Practice\Game\app.js:5:5)
    at onclick (c:\Users\C2Ran\Practice\Game\index.html:16:82)
```

Shouldn't `grid` be globally defined? Why isn't app.js able to access it? And finally, why can't I define my function inside a module in the first place?

Comment: swap the `script` lines, in HTML you don't use `import` but link/include the files in the right order

Comment: @rioV8 — You're rather out of date. [In HTML we do use `import` now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Quentin if he wants to use `mathimport` as a module, he has to import it in `app.js` and to do that it must be known so he has to swap the 2 `script` lines, `grid` is a variable in the module `mathimport`, without a reference to `mathimport` `app.js` can't find `grid`, he has to import `mathimport` and use `mathimport.grid` or import `grid` from `mathimport`

Comment: @rioV8 — No. The script elements shouldn't be swapped. The script element loading *mathimport.js* needs to be **replaced** by an `import` statement in *app.js*.

Comment: from the `mdn` website: Although imported features are available in the file, **they are read only views** of the feature that was exported. You **cannot change the variable** that was imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the exports from a module, then that module can't be the entry point for the program. Exports are not turned into globals.

The code that needs to use it must import it, which requires that it be a module.

1. Remove `<script type="module" src="mathimport.js" defer></script>`.
2. Make `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>` a module
3. `import` *mathimport.js* inside *app.js*

You'll then need to do something with `play` to use it. Currently *app.js* only defines it. It never calls it / assigns it as an event handler / etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `grid` in app.js file

Like this:-
`ìmport {grid} from 'mathimport.js'`